# Android Glide without resizing imageview

Tags: android, android-glide

I've started an app where I'm getting images from a RESTful server in response to the user clicking on another component on the screen. I've set it up so that it gets the data back, creates a byte array and displays that on the screen - all good.

However I've learnt that this may have memory leaks and the best way to load images is with glide. I've got the simple glide working but it has problems.  Specifically when I reload an image onto an image view the component shrinks to a height of zero and then resizes again.  How can I say to Glide - keep the component the same size during the transition? Crossfade doesn't work and I can't see anything that can do this.

EDIT

The code with the glide is as follows:

```
Glide.with(this)
  .load(Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT))
  .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cutoutImageView));
```

The image variable is a string containing the images retrieved from a RESTful service.

The XML defining the imageview is as follows:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cutoutImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/annotatedImageView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="1dp"/>
```

Note that I can't hardcode the size of the image view because I don't know what size image I'll be getting from the RESTful service until I get it.  I do know that once I get one image then the subsequent images will all be the same size though.

Another issue is that glide wants to scale the iamge - I don't I want to show the image at the size I get it.  How do I do that?

Comment: Could you please share the code where you are using glide? Also please share the xml code for your ImageView

Comment: use RequestOptions from here https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html

Comment: Thanks; I've looked at that but - what specific Request options do I need to a not scale the image and b not reduce the size of the image view when switching between images?